# Django ternary models relationship with constraints

Tags: django, database, django-models, constraints

As part of a Django online platform that offers online courses, course authors are free to include exercises from a public exercise repository.

Each course has its own chapters and is free with how to organize the exercises in chapters.

An exercise in a course can be part of zero or one chapter.
When a chapter in a course is deleted, the exercises in it just go back to the status of no chapter assigned.

What I have so far :

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise)


class Chapter(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**The problem:**
There is no link between exercises and course chapters so far, it isn't clear to me how to do it in a proper way taking into consideration the constraint that an exercise in a chapter should be in the course as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It says that You first have to create the course(mandatory). And then you can either create a chapter or a course while creating chapter mandatorily you have to relate it to a course. While creating exercise you have to relate it to a course(mandatory) but not a Chapter but if it is related to a chapter and that chapter is later deleted then the chapter filed of Exercise will be unassigned or set NULL.

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     course = models.ForeignKey(Course, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) #if you want the exercise to be deleted when a course is deleted set it to CASCADE
     chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Chapter(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this is, if I get it right, with OneToOneField an instance of Exercise can only be linked to only one instance of ChapterExercise. But in my scenario,a same Exercise can be present in many courses, for each course in a different chapter. @Himanshu Poddar

Comment: change it to foreign key then

Comment: Lets start from the beginning, We have 3 tables `Exercise`, `Chapter`, `Course`. Course is an independent table its not related to anything(but other tables can be related to it). A chapter should be a part of the course. An exercise but can be either related to a course or a chapter. Right? So if an exercise is related to any chapter then that chapter has to be there in our course table. but an exercise if not related to any chapter can still be related to course independent of any chapter. Am I right? or tell me where did I go wrong so that I can solve your problem

Comment: I have a "public" table of exercises, course authors need to choose which ones they want to include in their course. Many courses can include the same exercise. So an exercise is always related to a course.
Now, each course can create and manage its own chapters, and select which exercise goes into which chapter. Putting an exercise in a chapter is optional.
So in conclusion, an exercise is always related to a course, a chapter is always related to a course, an exercise is optionally related to a chapter related to the course the exercise is related to.

Comment: It is still not correct because an *same* exercise can be present in different courses, thus the many2many I originally wrote.

Comment: Foreign key will take care of it. You try once. since we haven;t specified any unique constraint in our exercise table.

Comment: @protoneight can an exercise exist without any relation to course? i.e independently

Comment: Yes it can exist in the exercises table without any course having it